# Can I create document (pushpin) issues via api?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I want to integrate my web api with bim360 api.
In my app I need to create pushpin issues. Can I do it by bim360 api?

The documentation says yes and no:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issues/create-issues/
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-POST/

What is the truth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion, but pushpin issue was supported recently, you can check the [ChangeLog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/change_history/issues_v1_changelog/) for the information.

I believe the doc is not updated well, will report this to internal documentation team. But you should be able to create pushpin issue following the tutorial at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/pushpins/create-pushpin/, if any issue, feel free to let us know.

Comment: This tutorial describes how to do it via ForgeViewer lib. But I don't want to use ForgeViewer. I want to create pushpin via rest api.

Comment: I've already sent https://developer.api.autodesk.com/issues/v1/containers/:container_id/quality-issues request with pushpin_attributes,  sheet_metadata and target_urn. And it seems to work (I can see pushpin issue in bim360). But https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-POST/ request body structure says nothing about this attributes. And I'm not sure that it is full supported approach.

Comment: I don't think you can create pushpin issue without viewer because you need to specify the position within the document. Please check the sample https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360-csharp-issues on the implementation, and https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360-csharp-issues/blob/master/bim360issues/wwwroot/js/BIM360IssueExtension.js about the details. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can set the position in pushpin_attributes: pushpin_attributes = new
                        {
                            type = "TwoDRasterPushpin",
                            location = new
                            {
                                x = -0.24721770748422858,
                                y = 0.432498789973707,
                                z = 0
                            }
                        }

Comment: But I'm not sure if issue created that way is consistent. If I get issues details created by ForgeViewer and create a new one via post /issues/v1/containers/:container_id/quality-issues method, with exactly the same attributes - will the both be correct? I wonder if ForgeViewer doesn't do something more than I can do be calling this api method?

Comment: If you can get the correct position and object from the model, yes, you can use the rest API to create pushpin, it will be consistent with the way by ForgeViewer. We just suggest to use the ForgeViewer way to make it be consistent as the way in BIM360.