# Can I create BIM 360 Pushpin issues using server-side APIs (not Forge Viewer)?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

In the https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/pushpins/create-pushpin/ documentation sample it shows how to create a document-related (Pushpin) issue, but it utilizes the Autodesk Forge Viewer to get the selected sheet in the document (attributes.sheet_metadata.sheetGuid), the location on the sheet (attributes.pushpin_attributes.location), and the view state (attributes.pushpin_attributes.viewer_state) in order to be passed to the actual server-side POST /issues/v1/containers/{container-id}/quality-issues API call.

What I need is to call only the server-side API, as I need to enter hundreds of issues automatically without showing the Viewer for each issue I add to BIM 360.
Is there any way to get the sheets GUIDs from a BIM 360 document to insert to the call without the Viewer Frontend API, as well as a programatic way to generate issue.position and issue.viewerState objects to pass to the call?

I have reviewed the question [Can I create document (pushpin) issues via api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54124229/can-i-create-document-pushpin-issues-via-api) , it is pointing to the same direction, but doesn't give details on how to use the server-side APIs to implement this.

```js
var issue = PushPinExtensionHandle.getItemById('0');

var data = {

    sheet_metadata: { // `viewerApp.selectedItem` references the current sheet
      is3D: viewerApp.selectedItem.is3D(),
      sheetGuid: viewerApp.selectedItem.guid(),
      sheetName: viewerApp.selectedItem.name()
    },
    pushpin_attributes: { // Data about the pushpin
      type: 'TwoDVectorPushpin', // This is the only type currently available
      object_id: issue.objectId, // (Only for 3D models) The object the pushpin is situated on.
      location: issue.position, // The x, y, z coordinates of the pushpin.
      viewer_state: issue.viewerState // The current viewer state. For example, angle, camera, zoom.
    },
  }
};
```

I'm using NodeJS, but any code sample in other languages would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I had achieved this by reverse-engineering the HTTP requests made by the viewer when creating BIM360 issues. Here's my code that creates issues from server side, using Node.js: https://github.com/petrbroz/poc-hololens-bim360/blob/develop/helpers/forge/bim360.js#L73-L131.